# Android: Loading Ad delays SharedElementTransition

Tags: android, performance, admob, shared-element-transition

I got a problem with implementing a smooth shared element transition. When starting this animation, it seems as if Android renders the `DetailActivity` with its content first and afterwards start the shared element transition.

My DetailActivity contains some simple views like `TextView` and `ImageView`, but also an `AdView` with this code:

```
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("ausgabe", mAdViewEdition);

        final PublisherAdRequest adRequest = new PublisherAdRequest.Builder()
            .setManualImpressionsEnabled(true)
                .addNetworkExtras(
                new AdMobExtras(bundle)).build();

        mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                if (mLayout != null && mAdView != null) {
                    mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                if (mAdView != null && mLayout != null) {
                    mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });


        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Every first time I start the shared element transition the `loadAd` method takes up to two seconds till an ad is fully loaded. Because of that the shared element transition also delays up to two seconds, which is causing a bad user experience. If I do not call the `loadAd` method the animation works well.

Anybody got an idea on how to fix this issue? I already tried to put the `loadAd` method in an `AsyncTask`, but this doesn't work neither since the method has to be called from the UI Thread.

Comment: Does the delay happen the first time you load an ad, or every time? There can be some additional overhead on the first request made after starting an app.

Comment: Yes, it only happens the first time I load the app. But is there any way to load the ad in the background or after the transition has finished? It's a bad first impression of an app if the animation delays for two seconds at the beginning

Comment: I completely understand. Since you're using PublisherAdViews, you can actually create one without adding it to the view hierarchy, request an ad with an ad unit like "/your_network/some_nonexistent_ad_unit", then throw it away when the request comes back as failed to load. That should get you over the initial delay, and subsequent requests should be much faster. FWIW, we're putting some stuff into our next release that should fix this issue, so keep an eye out.

Comment: That sounds nice @RedBrogdon. I'm looking forward to this next release ;-) For now I'll try your suggested solution, thanks for your help :)